# How to fix a Key vault Reference in a configuration of logic app standard on a different location than key vault

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I have a logic app standard that is on a different location than the key vault.

Logic app - `North Europe`

Key Vault - `West Europe`

I gave the logic app an access policie in Key Vault for it to be able to get/retrieve secrets.

[image]

The problem is that in the configuration section of the logic app the reference is failing.

[image]

I have also, a private endpoint for the key vault configurated for the `North Europe` location, but even using that private endpoint url it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Is using a Managed Identity the best alternative?

Or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t use a managed identity and flick your auth method to RBAC? That could be a nicer way to do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Skin, no i'm using it this way since it was architected calling the key vault reference, i also have a private endpoint for key vault for the Nort Europe location. But still, it doesn't work or i don't know how to use it. I already have app services using managed identity, is it the right way to solve this?

Comment: @skin BTW when you mean RBCA are you referring to key vault?